# What happens when you go to sleep mode in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, sleep

Title says it all, but specifically

1. Does Wifi get turned off?
2. How much CPU power is being reduced and how much battery is saved?
3. Does the graphics card still run when on sleep mode?

Comment: It depends entirely on the settings of your computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **What happens when you go to sleep mode in Windows 10**

Below are a couple good references to the topic of the question as the title asks:

> ### [Shut down, sleep, or hibernate your PC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13770/windows-shut-down-sleep-hibernate-your-pc)
>
> **Sleep**
>
> This uses very little power, your PC starts up faster, and you’re
>   instantly back to where you left off. You don’t have to worry that
>   you'll lose your work because of your battery draining, because
>   Windows automatically saves all your work and turns off the PC if the
>   battery is too low. Use sleep when you’re going to be away from your
>   PC for just a little while—like when you’re taking a coffee break.
>
> <sub>[source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13770/windows-shut-down-sleep-hibernate-your-pc)</sub>

---

> ### [Four Windows 10 Power Settings You Should Probably Change (Hibernation and Sleep)](http://www.michaellinenberger.com/blog/four-windows-10-power-settings-you-should-probably-change-hibernation-and-sleep/)
>
> Sleep stores the state of your computer in RAM, and so resumes much
>   faster; you’ll be up and running in two to five seconds in some cases.
>   However, sleep uses a fair amount of battery power. So it makes sense
>   to decide which of these you want to use and when. The default
>   settings are, in my opinion, not ideal for most usage cases.
>
> <sub>[source](http://www.michaellinenberger.com/blog/four-windows-10-power-settings-you-should-probably-change-hibernation-and-sleep/)</sub>

---

> 1. Does Wifi get turned off
> 2. How much CPU power is being reduced and how much battery is saved.
> 3. Does the graphics card still run when on sleep mode

For the question about the **Graphics Card** and the **WiFi**, those are not operational in sleep mode until the PC wakes from the mode.

For the **CPU** question, that will depend on the sleep state you have configured, see these two resources for more detail on these states:

- [System Power States](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373229(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [System Sleeping States](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564575%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For the **Battery** question that depends on many factors as well but see here for a good read:

- [How Much Battery Life Does Sleep Mode Really Drain?](http://lifehacker.com/5526542/how-much-battery-life-does-sleep-mode-really-drain)

Answer (score 4):

'Sleep mode' *in a nutshell* stops the CPU's clocking, so the CPU stops right where it is. The memory is still powered, and everything else does nothing.

When you wake the computer 'up', the clocking starts, and it moves right on.

Because the CPU does not react to interrupts while it 'sleeps' (except the 'wake-up' call), all external access it disabled, so no wireless, no internal clock updating, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes, wifi is turned off (if your computer is not set up to be awaken remotely from network)
2. cpu and battery consumption are very low (aprox. under 0,1%)
3. no, grafics card is shut down

(fyi all jobs that you are running will be frozen till power on. even if you do a heavy cpu work like encoding of the movie)

Answer (score 0):

my laptop has virus scans set up for 3 AM every day of the week.
However I often note that my AVG package tells me it has not done a scan for 10 or more days. My power setting is to put the computer to sleep when I close the lid.
Is that the problem?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).